# SVG half of a circle

Tags: css, svg

How can I rotate the circle 180 degrees in the SVG, not with CSS? I mean only having the top of the SVG not the bottom.

```html
<svg width="135" height="135">
    <path d="M10,80 a60,60 0 0,0 115,0" fill="#f7ad1a" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third `0` (fifth parameter) to the `a` (arc) command is the "sweep flag".  Change it from a `0` (anti-clockwise) to a `1` (clockwise).  It will then go the other direction, around the circle, from the start to the end point.

```html
<svg width="135" height="135">
    <path d="M10,80 a60,60 0 0,1 115,0" fill="#f7ad1a" />
</svg>
```